# What can I do with my Primordial Shrieks?

Tags: fallen-london

I have a lot of items I don't know what to do with, but slowly they seem to become useful for various things.

Primordial Shrieks, though, I have no idea what to do with. I have a lot of them and I seem to just keep getting more from packages I open.

What can I do with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a basic Wild Words item, the primary use for Primordial Shrieks is to convert them up to [Maniac's Prayers](http://echobazaar.wikidot.com/maniac-s-prayer).

You can use Primordial Shrieks in batches of 1, 50, and 500 by clicking on Primordial Shrieks in your inventory, which you can find on the "Myself" tab.

Here are the choices you currently have:

[image: Choices]

There is also [a list of other uses](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Primordial_Shriek) at the Fallen London Wikia, but they are few and far between.

As with most things in Fallen London, you could of course pawn your Primordial Shrieks at the Bazaar, where they sell for 2 pence each.

Comment: Some things to add: This process is useful because when you convert Primordial Shrieks into Maniac's Prayers, the Maniac's Prayers created sell for slightly more than the Primordial Shrieks you used to make them would have. Additionally, although I'm not very far along and can't confirm this, Maniac's Prayers and the items that they themselves are used to create are useful for understanding the Correspondence, whatever that is.